# Connecting to colab from a python script elsewhere

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I currently have an ML algorithm that I have been using colab to train, as running this model is pretty heavy, I was wondering if it is possible to connect a python script that I have on for example my laptop to colab, e.g. uploading an input to my ML algorithm and then getting the output sent back?

I have googled pretty heavily on this but I am unable to find anyone discussing tying regular python scripts to my colab output.

Comment: nope you cannot.because colab creates new virtual ubuntu machine for you.you can't communicate directly to your local machine.if you want to communicate notebook means use jupyter library.

Comment: Why cant I just start the VM and then communicate with it?

Comment: nope becuase there's no communication between your computer and colab.only medium is browser. only you can transfer your input via mqtt or any other protocols and the catch that in colab then you should give that to your ML algorithm.

Comment: Okay so thats the point, there is no API interface with colab?